# ColdFusion Application.cfm cfinclude not working

Tags: coldfusion

I have a function called "conv" which is needed in several programs within my application.  So rather than include it in each program, I put it in the Application.cfm, which looked like this:

```
<cfapplication name = "Moxware" sessionmanagement = "Yes">  
<cfset lang = "LU">
<cfset x127 = Chr(127)>   
<cfset mmox = 'Moxware'>
<cfinclude template="conv.cfc">
```

When I ran one of the programs using the function "conv" (which is in conv.cfc) I got an error that the function `conv` could not be found.

After I hunted around the internet for ideas I tried this:

```
<cfapplication name = "Moxware" sessionmanagement = "Yes">  
<cfset lang = "LU">
<cfset x127 = Chr(127)>   
<cfset mmox = 'Moxware'>
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" output="true" returntype="void">
   <cfinclude template="conv.cfc">
</cffunction>
```

That gave me the same error message as before.

Can someone explain to me how to do this?

Note that the function `conv` was tested and works just fine.

Comment: i uh, don't think that's how it works. you'll want to create an instance of the cfc and make it available to the app through one of the scopes, such as application.

Comment: @KevinB's comment is the correct answer to this question.

Comment: Could you help me out here a little further?  How do I make it available through the application scope?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using an include, like this...

```
<cfinclude template="conv.cfc">
```

Try creating an object, like this...

```
<cfscript>
 MyObject = createObject("component", "conv");
</cfscript>
```

When you want to access a function within that object, try this...

```
<cfscript>
 SomeValue = MyObject.MyFunction();
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include CFM pages into the CFC, but I don't think you can include CFC code into a CFC.

So this is possible...

```
<cffunction name="OnRequest" access="public" returntype="void" output="true" hint="Fires after pre page processing is complete.">

    <cfargument name="TargetPage" type="string" required="true" />

    <cfinclude template = "/myMapping/onRequestStart_include.cfm" />

    <cfinclude template = "/myMapping/onRequest_include.cfm" />

    <cfinclude template = "/myMapping/onRequestEnd_include.cfm" />

</cffunction>
```

Note the use of a mapping (in our case /myMapping), which can help if your doing this in CFC's. If no mapping is needed, just drop that.

But probably the best option is to instantiate your CFC from within the Application.cfc and use it.

```
<cfset myConv = createObject("component", "myMapping.conv").init() />
```

Again using a mapping to get to the CFC. The .init() is not always needed, depends how your CFC is setup.

Then presumably conv has methods you want to use (You talk about it as a single function? A cfc is essentially an object, so you create it as an object first and then use it's methods), so then you'd invoke then by using...

```
myConv.functionName()
```

Put another way - Application.cfc is no different from anywhere else in your code. How ever it's invoked and used elsewhere is how you should do it here. The only trick might be pathing to that CFC, which you can do by creating a custom mapping.

Also consider going old school (if it is just a function), and using custom-tags.

Good luck.